Show that inner product of exterior powers does not depend on the choice of basis?
I am reading Differential Forms and Connections by Darling.
Inner product of exterior powers is defined as follows:
An inner product $\left\langle\cdot,\cdot\right\rangle$ is given for a vector space $V$.
As an extension of that, an inner product is defined on $\wedge ^pV$ is given by:
$$
\left\langle u_1\wedge u_2\wedge\ldots\wedge u_p, v_1\wedge v_2\wedge\ldots\wedge v_p\right\rangle = \det\left[\left(a_{ij}\right)_{i,j\ =\ 1,2,\ldots,p}\right],
$$
where $a_{ij} = \left\langle u_{i},v_{j}\right\rangle$ and $u_{1}\wedge u_{2}\wedge\ldots\wedge u_{p}$ and $v_{1}\wedge v_{2}\wedge\ldots\wedge v_{p}$ are elements of the basis of $\wedge^{p}V$.
I am told that the definition of the inner product does not depend on the choice of basis, but have no idea how to prove that.
Anyone knows how to show it ?. Thank you !.

Update:
I thought over it and think that I know how to show it now. It is pretty tedious though.
It is clear from the definition that once we fix a basis, an inner product is defined.
It rest to show that we have the same inner product defined on $\wedge^p V$ no matter what basis we choose.
To show it, start from a basis $(e_1,e_2,...,e_n)$ of $V$, then $\{e_{i_1}\wedge ...\wedge e_{i_p}\}_{i_1<i_2<...<i_p}$ is a basis of $\wedge^p V$. Define the inner product on $\wedge^p V$ using this basis.
Let $u_i=\sum_j\alpha_{ij}e_j$ and $v_i=\sum_j\beta_{ij}e_j$. According to the inner product defined based on $\{e_{i_1}\wedge ...\wedge e_{i_p}\}_{i_1<i_2<...<i_p}$, we have
$$<u_1\wedge...,\wedge u_p, v_1\wedge...\wedge v_p>=<\sum_j\alpha_{1j}e_j\wedge...\wedge\sum_j\alpha_{pj}e_j,\sum_j\beta_{1j}e_j\wedge...\wedge\sum_j\beta_{pj}e_j>$$
$$=\sum_{k_1,...,k_p,l_1,...,l_p\in\{1,...n\}} <\alpha_{1k_1}e_{k_1}\wedge...\wedge \alpha_{pk_p}e_{k_p}, \beta_{1l_1}e_{l_1}\wedge...\wedge \beta_{pl_p}e_{l_p}>=\sum_{k_1,...,k_p,l_1,...,l_p\in\{1,...n\}}  \det[(<\alpha_{ik_i}e_{k_i},\beta_{jl_j}e_{l_j}>)_{i,j=1,...,p}].$$
On the other hand, we revisit the original definition in the question, i.e., $$<u_1\wedge...,\wedge u_p, v_1\wedge...\wedge v_p>=\det[(<u_i,v_j>)_{i,j=1,...,p}]=\det[(<\sum_k\alpha_{ik}e_k,\sum_l\beta_{jl}e_l>)_{i,j=1,...,p}].$$
Using the linearity of $\det$, $$\det[(<\sum_k\alpha_{ik}e_k,\sum_k\beta_{jk}e_k>)_{i,j=1,...,p}]=\sum_{k_1,...,k_p,l_1,...,l_p\in\{1,...n\}}  \det[(<\alpha_{ik_i}e_{k_i},\beta_{jl_j}e_{l_j}>)_{i,j=1,...,p}].$$
The calculations above shows that the two inner products defined by different basis are identical.

Your reasoning seems fine, but are you sure you're reading Darling right? (I don't know, I've never read it.) If so, then this is an exceedingly silly and convoluted way of defining the inner product. If you're familiar with the universal property of ${\bigwedge^p}V$, then defining the inner product requires nothing more than the determinant equation you presented with no need to restrict $u_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge u_p$ and $v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_p$ to basis elements; because the RHS is alternating in the $u_i$ and $v_j$ (separately), you automatically have a well-defined inner product on ${\bigwedge^p}V$ with no need to appeal to any bases at all (and so it is automatically basis-independent).

Thank you! I cannot upvote because I do not have enough reputation. Do you have any reference book/resource on that? I am reading Darling and it is the definition in the book.

@Alex You should be able to click on the check mark to accept the answer. I have not dived into differential geometry, so I do not have a recommendation for that specifically. However, for exterior algebra I can recommend Werner Greub's Multilinear Algebra. This will definitely cover the universal property of ${\bigwedge^p}V$, and then you can do what I said above to define the inner product.

Greub covers the "inner product" in a different way though; he instead defines the pairing $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:{\bigwedge}V^\times{\bigwedge}V \to \mathbb R$ by deriving the interior product $$(\Omega, X) \mapsto i_{\Omega}X:{\bigwedge}V^\times{\bigwedge}V\to{\bigwedge}V,$$ which is equal to the pairing when restricted to ${\bigwedge^p}V^\times{\bigwedge^p}V$. The pairing is easily related to the inner product by extending the musical isomorphism $V\cong V^$ to ${\bigwedge}V\cong{\bigwedge}V^*$.
